# Uri to scaled Bitmap Kotlin code displays the image rotated on its side

Tags: android, kotlin, uri, android-jetpack-compose, android-bitmap

I have Kotlin code that scales down the `Uri` image to a `Bitmap` and back to a `Uri`. Although the code successfully scales the image, it displays it rotated onto its side. What could be wrong with the code?

**Composable**

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = "tobitmaps") {
    uriResult.value = resizeImage(
        context,
        viewModel.state.value.imageUri
    )
}

uriResult.value?.let { imageUri ->
    AsyncImage(
        imageUri,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
}
```

**Scaling Functions**

```
suspend fun resizeImage(context: Context,  uri: Uri?): Uri? {
    val resizedBitmap = decodeUri(context, uri, 400)

    val uri = bitmapToFile(context, resizedBitmap!!, "testingfile")?.let {
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.testapp.app.fileprovider", it)
    }

    return uri
}

fun decodeUri(c: Context, uri: Uri?, requiredSize: Int): Bitmap? {
    return try {
        val o = BitmapFactory.Options()
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true
        
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri!!), null, o)
        var width_tmp = o.outWidth
        var height_tmp = o.outHeight
        var scale = 1
        
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < requiredSize || height_tmp / 2 < requiredSize) break
            width_tmp /= 2
            height_tmp /= 2
            scale *= 2
        }
        
        val o2 = BitmapFactory.Options()
        o2.inSampleSize = scale
        
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri!!), null, o2)
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}

 fun bitmapToFile(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap, fileNameToSave: String): File? {
    var file: File? = null
    return try {
        file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + File.separator + fileNameToSave + ".png")
        file.createNewFile()

        //Convert bitmap to byte array
        val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos) // YOU can also save it in JPEG
        val bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray()

        //write the bytes in file
        val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
        fos.write(bitmapdata)
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()
        file
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        file // it will return null
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is ok. But the jpg file contains -exif-orientation information for the image too. Read that information and then rotate the bitmap accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please use updated code below (where 1612 is the new height in PX of your image):

```
private fun resizeImage(context: Context, uri: Uri?): Uri? {
    val bitmap = getBitmap(context.contentResolver, uri)
    val resizedBitmap = bitmap?.let { resizeBitmap(it, 1612) }

    val uri = bitmapToFile(context, resizedBitmap!!, "testingfile")?.let {
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.testapp.app.fileprovider", it)
    }

    return uri
}

private fun getBitmap(contentResolver: ContentResolver, fileUri: Uri?): Bitmap? {
    return try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, fileUri!!))
        } else {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, fileUri)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception){
        null
    }
}

private fun resizeBitmap(source: Bitmap, maxLength: Int): Bitmap {
    try {
        if (source.height >= source.width) {
            if (source.height <= maxLength) {
                return source
            }

            val aspectRatio = source.width.toDouble() / source.height.toDouble()
            val targetWidth = (maxLength * aspectRatio).toInt()
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, maxLength, false)
        } else {
            if (source.width <= maxLength) {
                return source
            }

            val aspectRatio = source.height.toDouble() / source.width.toDouble()
            val targetHeight = (maxLength * aspectRatio).toInt()
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, maxLength, targetHeight, false)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return source
    }
}

private fun bitmapToFile(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap, fileNameToSave: String): File? {
    var file: File? = null
    return try {
        file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + File.separator + fileNameToSave + ".jpeg")
        file.createNewFile()

        //Convert bitmap to byte array
        val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos)
        val bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray()

        //write the bytes in file
        val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
        fos.write(bitmapdata)
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()
        file
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        file // it will return null
    }
}
```